# XCode: Different UI for different device sizes

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I would like to apply design A for iPhone3.5in, and design B for all other iPhones. In XCode storyboard, I thought changing the size constraints was there for this purpose but they don't seem to have any effect. More specifically, I want to apply the first design below for iPhone3.5in, and the second one for all the other iphone devices. [image: Design A] [image: Design B] Someone suggested that there is no way to do it in XCode and I should do it programmatically but I believe there must be a way. Thank you so much for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

@maximus, Try below Code..

Create macro->>

```
#define IS_IPHONE_4 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480.0f)
```

& Use Below Code When you have to Implement it.

```
        NSString *nibName;
        if (IS_IPHONE_4)   //Check Whether is iPhone4s or not
        {
            nibName=@"DCHomeViewController";
        }
        else
        {
            nibName=@"DCHomeViewControlleri5";
        }

self.homeViewCOntroller=[[DCHomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil];
```

in short, try to call diff nib for iPhone4s & and diff for Other..

Comment: Thank you, but this does not use the storyboard.

Comment: @MaximusS, Then You have to Create Programatically Logic for Design in your ViewDidLoad Method..

Answer (score 0):

The size constraints allows you to see how the view will look like in different size. If you set auto-resize or autolayout, you will see how it was changed. If the layout is totally different, you have to do it programmatically .